# Rails 3.1 - Simple search across three (or more) models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have three models that i'd like to perform a simple search across:

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_releases
  has_many :artists, :through => :artist_releases  
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy     
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :release
  has_many :artists, :through => :releases        
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_releases
  has_many :releases, :through => :artist_releases
end
```

In my Product Controller i can successfully render a product list searching across release and product using:

```
@products = Product.find(:all, :joins => :release, :conditions => ['products.cat_no LIKE ? OR releases.title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%","%#{params[:search]}%"])
```

I really need to be able to search artist as well. How would I go about doing that? I ideally need it within the Product Controller as it's a product list I need to display.

I've tried adding :joins => :artist and variations thereof, but none seem to work.

I'm aware there are options out there like Sphinx for a full search, but for now I just need this simple approach to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want products back, just add both joins:

```
@products = Product.joins(:release,:artists).where('products.cat_no LIKE :term OR releases.title LIKE :term OR artists.name LIKE :term', :term => "%#{params[:search]}%").all
```

You may also need group_by to get distinct products back.

if you want polymorphic results, try 3 separate queries.

Comment: This looks great, exactly what I need, however, it's giving me an error: `HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError in ProductsController - Could not find the association :releases in model Product` I know it's not a Has Many Through so how do we make it expect the one to many relationship?

Comment: note the singular ':release' in the join association name, while plural 'releases.title' in the table name. Crucial :)

Comment: Yes, I have it like that. As I test I removed all references to release and the error is always the same!?!

Comment: oh your error is simply cos you have a typo in product: :through => :release not :releases, the through association here is a belongs_to

Comment: Ah! Interesting how that's not produced any errors elswhere! Works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm suggesting a simple approach (and probably not the most efficient) but it will get your job done:

I would create a method in your Product model similar to this:

```
def find_products_and_artists
  results = []
  Product.find(:all, :conditions => ['products.cat_no LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"]).each do |prod|
    results << prod
  end
  Release.find(:all, :conditions => ['releases.title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"]).each do |rel|
    results << rel
  end
  Artist.find(:all, :conditions => ['artist.name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"]).each do |art|
    results << art
  end
  return results
end
```

Then when you call it the method and store the returned results in a variable (e.g. `results`), you can check what object each element is by doing

```
results[i].class
```

and can make your code behave accordingly for each object.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks I think Viktor's answer is closer to what I had in mind, but that is giving me an error so i'll see if I can get your suggestion to work. Many thanks